# SQL Insert fails on i.name does not exist, when it seemingly does, during insert

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, postgresql-9.5

I'm using Postgres SQL and pgAdmin. I'm attempting to copy data between a staging table, and a production table using INSERT INTO with a SELECT FROM statement with a to_char along the way. This may or may not be the wrong approach. The SELECT fails because apparently "column i.dates does not exist".

The question is: **Why am I getting 'column i.dates does not exist'**?

The schema for both tables is identical except for a date conversion.

I've tried matching the schema of the tables with the exception of the to_char conversion. I've checked and double checked the column exists.

This is the code I'm trying:

```
INSERT INTO weathergrids (location, dates, temperature, rh, wd, ws, df, cu, cc)
  SELECT
    i.location AS location,
    i.dates as dates,
    i.temperature as temperature,
    i.rh as rh,
    i.winddir as winddir,
    i.windspeed as windspeed, 
    i.droughtfactor as droughtfactor,
    i.curing as curing,
    i.cloudcover as cloudcover
  FROM (
      SELECT location, 
             to_char(to_timestamp(dates, 'YYYY-DD-MM HH24:MI'), 'HH24:MI YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'), 
             temperature, rh, wd, ws, df, cu, cc 
       FROM wosweathergrids
  ) i;
```

The error I'm receiving is:

```
ERROR:  column i.dates does not exist
LINE 4:  i.dates as dates,
         ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 151
```

My data schema is like:

```
+-----------------+-----+-------------+-----------------------------+-----+
|      TABLE      | NUM |   COLNAME   |          DATATYPE           | LEN |
+-----------------+-----+-------------+-----------------------------+-----+
| weathergrids    |   1 | id          | integer                     |  32 |
| weathergrids    |   2 | location    | numeric                     |   6 |
| weathergrids    |   3 | dates       | timestamp without time zone |     |
| weathergrids    |   4 | temperature | numeric                     |   3 |
| weathergrids    |   5 | rh          | numeric                     |   4 |
| weathergrids    |   6 | wd          | numeric                     |   4 |
| weathergrids    |   7 | wsd         | numeric                     |   4 |
| weathergrids    |   8 | df          | numeric                     |   4 |
| weathergrids    |   9 | cu          | numeric                     |   4 |
| weathergrids    |  10 | cc          | numeric                     |   4 |
| wosweathergrids |   1 | id          | integer                     |  32 |
| wosweathergrids |   2 | location    | numeric                     |   6 |
| wosweathergrids |   3 | dates       | character varying           |  16 |
| wosweathergrids |   4 | temperature | numeric                     |   3 |
| wosweathergrids |   5 | rh          | numeric                     |   4 |
| wosweathergrids |   6 | wd          | numeric                     |   4 |
| wosweathergrids |   7 | ws          | numeric                     |   4 |
| wosweathergrids |   8 | df          | numeric                     |   4 |
| wosweathergrids |   9 | cu          | numeric                     |   4 |
| wosweathergrids |  10 | cc          | numeric                     |   4 |
+-----------------+-----+-------------+-----------------------------+-----+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your derived table (sub-query) named `i` has no column named `dates` because the column `dates` is "hidden" in the `to_char()` function and as it does not define an alias for that expression, no column `dates` is available "outside" of the derived table.

But I don't see the reason for a derived table to begin with. Also: aliasing a column with the same name is also unnecessary `i.location as location` is exactly the same thing as `i.location`.

So your query can be simplified to:

```sql
INSERT INTO weathergrids (location, dates, temperature, rh, wd, ws, df, cu, cc)
SELECT
    location,
    to_timestamp(dates, 'YYYY-DD-MM HH24:MI'),
    temperature,
    rh,
    winddir,
    windspeed, 
    droughtfactor,
    curing,
    cloudcover
FROM wosweathergrids
```

You don't need to give an alias to the `to_timestamp()` expression as the column are matched by position, not by name in an `insert ... select` statement.